# Commutation relation

Tags: pattern-matching

I have defined:

```
COM[a_, b_] := a ** b - b ** a
```

for commutator bracket for the operators. We also have:

```
 SetAttributes[δ, Orderless]
    δ /: δ[a_, b_] h_[former___, b_, latter___] := 
     h[former, a, latter]
    δ[a_, a_] = 2*M;
    
    Format[δ[a_, b_]] := Subscript[δ, a, b]
```

If I have also  the following relation,

```
 a ** b = 2*δ[a, b] - b ** a
```

When I perform:

```
 Xij = (I/2)*COM[a, b]
```

Its output is not simplifying. Please see the mathematical output I am expecting.
[image: ddd]

Comment: The question is unclear. What result do you expect?

Comment: @xzczd Please see the modified question

Comment: I think you will want to do a pattern replacement method to do what you want here; your third code block does not appear to be valid Mathematica syntax.

Comment: Try setting upvalues in the third block, i.e.  `a ** b ^= 2*\[Delta][a, b] - b ** a`; otherwise the assignment as-is won't work unless you `Unprotect[NonCommutativeMultiply]`

Comment: Though given the text you're using, it seems you have an extra factor of `2` attached to `\[Delta]`?

Comment: @thorimur Agree and it's working

Comment: @thorimur Is it possible to generalize this as a rule?a_ ** b_ ^:= 2*\[Delta][a, b] - b ** a   is not working